# How to delete an entire row from a table in excel only if multiple cells are empty in that row? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I Have 10 columns in an Excel table, and I want to delete the rows where the first 7 cell is empty.
I've tried to do it this way:

```vb
Sheet1.Range("Table4[variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, variable6, variable7]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

but It doesn't work. Am I have to use nested for loop for rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop trough each row directly, and check if the first 7 cells of that row in your table are empty. If true, delete them.

```
Dim MyTable As ListObject
Dim i As Long

Set MyTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4")


With MyTable.DataBodyRange
    For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7))) = 7 Then .Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End With
```

The good point about this way is that if your table changes address, it still will work. You would only need to update if you want to check a different name of cells (seven rght now) or if the condition (7 first cells empty) changes.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking yes. Loop down the rows you want to check,

```
  For rowcounter = 1 to 10  'whatever rows you want
```

use the test

```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA("A" & rowcounter & ":G" & rowcounter) = 0 Then
```

(I assume first 7 columns meant A to G), and then

```
 Rows(rowcounter).Delete
```

Comment: Upon deleting rows, iterate backwards :)

Comment: Oh good point - so it should be for rowcounter = 10 to 1 step -1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple loops. A single loop with the use of the [IsEmpty() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function) should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,1)) And IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,2)) And IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(1,3)) And _
           IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,4)) And IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,5)) And _
           IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,6)) And IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i,7)) Then
               Sheet1.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this simple snippet, full of unnecessary procedures, can help you:

```
Sub NotTested()

    ' Choose below the rows range
    first_row = 2
    last_row = 4242

    For r = last_row To first_row Step -1

        ' Checking below each column (from row r) value
        a_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).Value2
        b_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2).Value2
        c_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3).Value2
        d_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 4).Value2
        e_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 5).Value2
        f_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 6).Value2
        g_value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 7).Value2

        ' Comparing if the columns are actually empty
        If a_value = "" And b_value = "" And c_value = "" And d_value = "" And e_value = "" And f_value = "" And g_value = "" Then            
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete             
        End If

    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that actually counts the number of rows in a table then deletes if the first 7 columns are blank.

```
Sub deleteEmptyRows()
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4")
For I = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & I & ":" & "G" & I)) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Be careful. Row number in a ListObject can be different that row number in worksheet. This code would work only if ListObject starts at row 1. IF not, you are deleting the wrong row